# write groovy email template to display parsed build errors in email body

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am using parsed console log plugin and Email-ext plugin in Jenkins to send out daily build status, only upon build failure or compiler warnings. I would like to display the extracted error/warning message in the email body. I got groovy email template from "https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template". It display Console Output instead of specific error/warning message want. 
I have zero knowledge on groovy or html et al, it gonna take me sometime to learn and able to modify the template to fulfill my need quickly.

Can someone point me a sample file that can search out either console output or parsed console output and only display the lines contain "error" or "warning"?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. Have you figured out a groovy script to read the build output log and display the extracted warnings/errors?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, much of the HTML here is quite ugly to be compatible with Outlook limited HTML support.

```
<%

def paddingForDepth(int depth)
{
    return "padding-left:${depth * 30}px";
}

def insertErrorPaneRow(int depth, Closure contents)
{
    %>
        <tr class="${tableLineClass()}">
            <td class="icon_cell"></td>
            <td class="console_cell"></td>
            <td class="phase_name_cell" style="${paddingForDepth(depth)}">
                <table width="100%" class="errorsPane">
    <%
    contents()
    %>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <%
}

def insertConsoleSummary(def build, int depth)
{
    if (build.result != hudson.model.Result.FAILURE)
        return;

    final BeforeSummary = 0
    final SummaryStarted = 1
    final SummaryEnded = 2

    BufferedReader logReader = new BufferedReader(build.getLogReader());
    List<String> errorLines = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<String> errorSummary = new LinkedList<String>();
    Boolean msBuildDetected = false;
    int scanStage = BeforeSummary;

    try
    {
        for (String line = logReader.readLine(); line != null; line = logReader.readLine())
        {
            if (line.contains(' error ') || line.contains(' warning '))
                errorLines.add(line);

            if (line.contains('Microsoft (R) Build Engine version '))
                msBuildDetected = true;

            if (msBuildDetected)
            {
                switch (scanStage)
                {
                case BeforeSummary:
                    if (line.equals('Build FAILED.') || line.equals('Build succeeded.'))
                        scanStage = SummaryStarted;
                    if (line.equals('Attempting to cancel the build...'))
                    {
                        scanStage = SummaryEnded;
                        msBuildDetected = false;
                    }
                    break;

                case SummaryStarted:
                    if (line ==~ /^\s*\d+ Warning\(s\)/)
                        scanStage = SummaryEnded;
                    else
                        errorSummary.add(line);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        logReader.close();
    }

    if ((msBuildDetected && (errorSummary.size() > 0)) || (errorLines.size() > 0))
    {
        insertErrorPaneRow(depth) {
            %><tr><td><pre><%
                if (msBuildDetected)
                    errorSummary.each { l -> println l }
                else
                    errorLines.each { l -> println l }
            %></pre></td></tr><%
        }
    }
}
%>

<STYLE>
.icon_cell { padding: 3px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; height:16px; vertical-align:middle; }
.console_cell { padding: 3px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 15px; height:16px; vertical-align:middle; }
.phase_name_cell { height:16px; vertical-align:middle; }
.errorsPane { background-color:#ffe0e0; }

</STYLE>
<BODY>
<!-- CONSOLE OUTPUT -->
<TABLE width="100%">
<TR><TD class="bg1"><B>BUILD SUMMARY</B></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<BR/>

<table border="0" class="phasesTable"><tbody>
<%
insertConsoleSummary(build, 0); 
%>
</tbody></table>
<BR/>

</BODY>
```